# I downloaded Ubuntu onto one of my HDD's and was then going to load it into a 4GB keyfob Any ideas on how to fix if possible? Tks

Tags: hard-drive

I downloaded Ubuntu installation files and I was expecting that after I would be able to disk image it onto a 4 GB USB stick but what seems to have happened is that it has overwritten part of my HDD and made the HDD invisible to Windows 10 and therefore I may have lost my windows files on that HDD. Was wondering if there was a way to remove the Ubuntu files and change it back into NTFS from CDFS and restore my files from that drive.

[Screen grab 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsmBs.png)

[Screen grab 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCpeg.png)

[screen grab 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H8MW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the installer already(booted into the flash drive and installed Ubuntu) / finish 'burning' to the usb drive you wanted the installer to be on?

From a close look at your screenshot you sent of the disk partitioning utility on Windows, you are just looking at the partitions of that specific device, in this case the USB you burned it onto. Your hard drive's files are still there--you're just looking at a different device and it's own partitions, which in this case, is a single partition containing the Ubuntu installer you need to boot from to install Ubuntu.

I would check the drives I have highlighted and make sure all the data/partitions you have on them hasn't been lost, just to be sure, but you're all good from a first glance. Windows seems to think that flash drive you have inserted is a CD, and there's a fix for that.

Assuming you've had a USB disk that got formatted as CDFS, you should be able to just reformat it to NTFS from Windows explorer, and if not, there are several tools you should be able to use to use to do the trick.

[image: The partitions that are likely still untouched]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even though the CDFS shows as a CD it's actually a 1TB HDD. I have two 1 TB HDD's and one 250GB SSD. Not sure what the disk 0 partition 3 and the system reserved stuff is. If I format the CD drive I presume it will delete whatever NTFS data was on there?